# How to scale GdkPixmap or XPixmap via X server?

Tags: x11, scale, gdk

I'm interested in offloading heavy computations from the X client. I think I can do so using XRender in some way, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GdkPixmap - by using Cairo.

XPixmap - by using next functions from XRender:

- XRenderSetPictureTransform
- XrenderComposite